# how do i fix execute reader not initalized

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to randomly select x amount of data from my database and output onto my website.

When I input any numbers into my textbox, I get an error:

> System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code
>   ExecuteReader: Connection property has not been initialized.

My code:

```
SqlConnection scon = new SqlConnection(@"User id=sa;Password=123;Server=.\sqlexpress03;Database=event");

StringBuilder htmlTable = new StringBuilder();
string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;

using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
{
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
    {
        con.Open();
        int a = Convert.ToInt32(shufflebox.Text);

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@shuffleno", shufflebox.Text.Trim());
        string query = "select top @shuffleno * from registered order by NEWID()";

        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, con))
        {
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();

            SqlDataReader articleReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            htmlTable.Append("<table border='1'>");
            htmlTable.Append("<tr><th>SlNo.</th>" +
                             "<th>Name</th>" +
                             "<th>Email ID</th>" +
                             "<th>Created Date</th></tr>");

            if (articleReader.HasRows)
            {
                    while (articleReader.Read())
                    {
                        htmlTable.Append("<tr>");
                        htmlTable.Append("<td>" + articleReader["userid"] + "</td>");
                        htmlTable.Append("<td>" + articleReader["username"] + "</td>");
                        htmlTable.Append("<td>" + articleReader["email"] + "</td>");
                        htmlTable.Append("<td>" + articleReader["createddate"] + "</td>");
                        htmlTable.Append("</tr>");
                    }
                    htmlTable.Append("</table>");

                    PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(new Literal { Text = htmlTable.ToString() });

                    articleReader.Close();
                    articleReader.Dispose();
                }
            }

        }


    }
}
```

Also, side question, how do I put textbox input in SQL queries?

I have an error when I tried using @shuffleno.

Comment: Nobody never read exception messages :( _"Connection property has not been initialized"_ means that you didn't initialize `Connection` property of your `SqlCommand`. Initialize it and you are good to go.

Comment: Why do you have **two** `SqlCommand` instances?? While you properly initialize `command` with both the query text and the connection, in the case of `cmd` you are **NOT** setting the connection - that's the cause of the error. Fix that.

Comment: @marc_s thank you so much, this has been solved :). I was severely confused as I'm still new to the structure and syntax, initializing command properly fixed it for me, thanks all :)

Comment: @Forevaplo: glad it got cleared up - it's called learning - we're all going through this over and over again  - don't worry :-)